# Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am using tflite for semantic segmentation. I have a model trained to segment objects from background, this model is trained on [deeplab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab).

I have converted this model(frozen inference graph) into tflite format using the below code:

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=test.lite \
  --graph_def_file=frozen_inference_graph.pb \
  --input_arrays=ImageTensor \
  --output_arrays=SemanticPredictions \
  --input_shapes=1,600,450,3 \
  --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=128
```

The model loads on  android, but when I try to run inference it gives me this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected
>   failure when preparing tensor allocations:
>   third_party/tensorflow/lite/kernels/unpack.cc:54 NumDimensions(input)
>
> > 1 was not true.Node number 4 (UNPACK) failed to prepare.

How do I resove this error?

Comment: Maybe the input shape was not right. You can post the code which you used to load and reshape the data in Android.

Comment: I am resizing the image to 513X385 in android studio and running inference on this resized image. I tried putting --input_shapes=1,450,600,3 \, --input_shapes=1,513,385,3 \ It does remove the error in both cases but it dosent seem to produce any output. On contrary the tfmobile model works perfectly fine on android

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I found out source of the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808705/how-to-custom-create-tflight-graph-to-match-that-of-googles-graph) but I dont know the solution would you mind taking a look on above posted link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for the below command:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco \
  --input_file=deeplabv3_mnv2_pascal_tain.pb \
  --output_file=test.tflite \
  --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8  \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --input_arrays=ImageTensor  \
  --output_arrays=SemanticPredictions  \
  --input_shapes=1,513,513,3 \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=128
```

It worked when I installed tensorflow from source. In order to install tensorflow from source I used ([link](https://github.com/ajinkya933/Installing-tensorflow-from-source-on-macOS/blob/master/Tensorflow%20installation%20from%20source))