# tflight graph created wrongly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I have the following frozen inference graph. This is for semantic segmentation using Deeplab ([download graph here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-kox31O1ZliAVWHzQ_MP3Jm7eqUUYEIE/view?usp=sharing)). I converting this graph to tflite format

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=test2.lite \
  --graph_def_file=frozen_inference_graph_3mbvoc.pb \
  --input_arrays=ImageTensor \
  --output_arrays=SemanticPredictions \
  --input_shapes=1,450,600,3 \
  --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=128
```

After conversion the graph looks as follows([download it here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uWcOCAHBcYwwf0yQSIJLlrctFNSr91oq/view?usp=sharing))
My question is how do I obtain graph similar to googles graph of deeplab available ([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wJ9RMFuZqs_TOW27ZPK6feToqmnNbepw/view?usp=sharing)) ? To give you a more clearer question please see below image [image]

the graph on left is my tflite graph and the graph on right is graph of deeplab by google. How do I obtain results similar to graph on right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tflite_convert \
  --output_file=test2.lite \
  --graph_def_file=frozen_inference_graph_3mbvoc.pb \
  --input_arrays=sub_2 \
  --output_arrays=ResizeBilinear_2 \
  --input_shapes=1,450,600,3 \
  --inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=128
```

This solved my question